# Retrieving Messages from SQS based on MessageAttributes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have added a few messages to an SQS Queue with a Message Attribute.

```
SendMessageRequest send_msg_request = new SendMessageRequest().withQueueUrl(queueUrl)
            .withMessageBody("Type 1Message")
            .addMessageAttributesEntry("Type1",  new MessageAttributeValue().withDataType("String").withStringValue("Type1"));
sqs.sendMessage(send_msg_request);

SendMessageRequest send_msg_request = new SendMessageRequest().withQueueUrl(queueUrl)
            .withMessageBody("Type 2 Message")
            .addMessageAttributesEntry("Type2",  new MessageAttributeValue().withDataType("String").withStringValue("Type2"));
sqs.sendMessage(send_msg_request);
```

And then retrieving the messages using

```
List<String> messageAttributeNames = new ArrayList<>();
messageAttributeNames.add("Type1");

ReceiveMessageRequest receiveMessage = new ReceiveMessageRequest().withQueueUrl(queueUrl)
            .withMessageAttributeNames(messageAttributeNames);
ReceiveMessageResult result = sqs.receiveMessage(receiveMessage);

List<Message> messages = result.getMessages();
```

But the receive call is returing messages with attribute name Type1 & Type2
Ive tried setMessageAttributes & withMessageAttributes, but in each case I'm getting both types back.

Is this the behavior of SQS or am I missing something? 
Appreciate any help.

Comment: I think you can request _which_ attributes to retrieve with the message, but you cannot use it to _filter_ which messages you receive.

Comment: As John said. Filtering is something you can do with _SNS_: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-message-filtering.html